# Bibliotecas em python para checar se um número é primo

Tags: python, biblioteca

Existe alguma biblioteca para determinar se o número é primo ou a única forma é criar o programa e executá-lo normalmente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar bibliotecas, mas realmente **não vejo necessidade** de instalar uma biblioteca adicional para algo "simples" e que **raramente** vai ser usado em algo sério.

Então a única biblioteca que vai necessitar é a biblioteca **nativa** `math` e com um *loop* (`while` por exemplo) e um calculo conseguirá o resultado, pode ser um script simples assim:

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
    start = 2;

    while start <= math.sqrt(n):
        if n % start < 1:
            return False;
        start += 1;

    return n > 1;


print(isPrime(12));
print(isPrime(13));
```

Baseado em [**Prime Numbers JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390131/1518921)

---

É importante que você **não vai** conseguir uma boa performance quando o numero é grande, nem escrevendo *"o melhor script de todos"* irá conseguir.

Segue um exemplo com números primos até 997, todos devem retornar `True`:

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
    start = 2;

    while start <= math.sqrt(n):
        if n % start < 1:
            return False;
        start += 1;

    return n > 1;


primos = [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47,
           53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107,
          109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
          173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229,
          233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283,
          293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359,
          367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431,
          433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491,
          499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571,
          577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641,
          643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709,
          719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787,
          797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859,
          863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941,
          947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

for numero in primos:
    print(isPrime(numero))
```

Exemplo online no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/@inphinit/isPrime)

Answer (score 1):

Sim existe. Existe o repositório de bibliotecas python, onde desenvolvedores colocam bibliotecas úteis para o desenvolvedor, entre elas, para envolvendo números primos.

[Bibliotecas envolvendo números primos](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=prime&submit=search)

Answer (score 0):

Ainda estou aprendendo python, e por isso para descobrir se um número é primo fiz esse programa:

```
    def calc(num, outro, raiz):
        if num%outro==0 and outro!=num:
            return False
        else:
            outro = outro+1
            if outro>>raiz:
                return True
            else:
                return calc(num, outro, raiz)
    
    import math
    num= input ('Entre com um número: ')
    num = int (num)
    if num == 1 or num == 0:
        print (f'Esse número não é primo e nem composto. Essa característica não é atribuída ao número {num}.')
    else:
        raiz=math.sqrt(num)
        raiz = int (raiz)
        outro=2
        resultado = calc (num, outro, raiz)
        if resultado == False:
            print (f'O número {num} não é primo.')

        else:
            print (f'O número {num} é primo.')
```

Answer (score -4):

Edit
Inicialmente, pedimos um número inteiro e positivo para o usuário e armazenamos na variável n.

Vamos armazenar na variável mult o número de múltiplos que existe de 2 até n-1.

Ou seja, do intervalo (2, 3, 4, ..., n-1)
Isso é obtido usando a função range: range(2,n).

Vamos usar a variável count pra receber cada um desses valores, dentro desse intervalo.

Dentro do looping, temos que testar se o resto da divisão de n por count vai ser 0. Se for, é porque n é múltiplo de count, logo não é primo.

A medida que nosso programa ai encontrando múltiplos, conta eles na variável mult e exibe na tela.

Após terminar o laço, testamos o valor de mult.
Se permanecer zerado, é porque o número fornecido pelo usuário é primo.

```
    `n = int(input("Verificar numeros 
      primos ate: "))
      mult=0

      for count in range(2,n):
      if (n % count == 0):
          print("Múltiplo de",count)
          mult += 1

      if(mult==0):
          print("É primo")
      else:
          print("Tem",mult," múltiplos 
           acima de 2 e abaixo de",n)`
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O AP não que saber se o número é par ou impar. O AP quer se o número é ou não primo.

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo, acho que agora ficou melhor, obrigado por avisarem, se tiverem problemas em entender eu tentarei simplificar mais